# No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization.IHtmlLocalizer' has been registered

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, localization, asp.net-core, globalization

I try with ASP.Core to have a multilanguages website. So, I have in my StartUp.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddLocalization();
    services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(
    opts =>
    {
        var supportedCultures = new[]
        {
            new CultureInfo("de-DE"),
            new CultureInfo("de"),
            new CultureInfo("fr-FR"),
            new CultureInfo("fr"),
        };
        opts.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("fr-FR");
        // Formatting numbers, dates, etc.
        opts.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
        // UI strings that we have localized.
        opts.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
    });
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
    services.AddMvc();
    // Add application services.
    services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();
    services.AddTransient<ISmsSender, AuthMessageSender>();
}
```

In my _ViewImports.cs I have:

```
@using System.Threading.Tasks
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Options

@inject IHtmlLocalizer Localizer
@inject IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions> LocOptions
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

The errors:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization.IHtmlLocalizer' has been registered.
```

Answer (score 31):

Add a type to the IHtmlLocalizer [like the docs demonstrate.](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/localization.html#view-localization)

```
@inject IHtmlLocalizer<MyType> MyTypeLocalizer
```

Also, I noticed that you have not registered the `ViewLocalization` service. You might need to do that too.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services
       .AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");

    services
      .AddMvc()
      .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix;

    ...
```

Comment: Thanks, services.AddMvc().AddViewLocalization() helps.

Comment: AddMvcLocalization() uses MvcLocalizationServices.AddMvcLocalizationServices. Which is register IHtmlLocalizer<> and IViewLocalizer

Answer (score 4):

Asp.net core 5:

```
services
.AddControllersWithViews()
.AddViewLocalization();
```